# Keras - throwing error that my input shape is 3 dimensional, when it is not

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, theano

My program takes in a CSV file where the first 6 rows are the inputs.

When defining the input I am using:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(2697, 6))
```

Where 2697 is the batch size and 6 is the input size. I know that `Input(shape=(batch-size, input-size))` is correct.

However when I run it I get a message:
***ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2697, 6)***

Why is keras picking this up as a 3 dimensional shape?

Answer (score 3):

From `Input` documentation:

> **Arguments**
>
> - shape: A shape tuple (integer), **not including the batch size**.
>     For instance, `shape=(32,)` indicates that the expected input
>     will be batches of 32-dimensional vectors.
> - batch_shape: A shape tuple (integer), **including the batch size**.
>     For instance, `batch_shape=(10, 32)` indicates that
>     the expected input will be batches of 10 32-dimensional vectors.
>     `batch_shape=(None, 32)` indicates batches of an arbitrary number
>     of 32-dimensional vectors.

So you can just change `shape` to `batch_shape`

```
Input(batch_shape=(2697, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not put the batch size dimension into the input shape, as Keras adds this automatically. This is why your two dimension input shape becomes three dimensional. Just change this line:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(6,))
```